# Can we perform multiplication using indexes of the list in jolt?

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to perform the multiplication of two different lists.

Is this possible to perform the multiplication corresponding indexes of the lists like list1[i] * list2[i].

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "salesTaxAmount": [
    5.2,
    5.2,
    5.2
  ],
  "quantity": [
    1,
    2,
    1
  ],
  "unitAmount": [
    20,
    20,
    20
  ]
}
```

**Expected output**

```json
{
  "totalAmount":[20,40,20]
}
```

Here I want the `totalAmount` like `quantity * unitAmount`.

Could someone help me, please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function such like *multiply* or *product* to be used within a **modify** spec but can be simulated by using **`divide`** function after reforming individual objects by a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "q*|u*": {
        "*": "&.&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "prd_quantity": "=divide(1,@(1,quantity))",
        "Amt_": "=divide(@(1,unitAmount),@(1,prd_quantity))",
        "Amt": "=toInteger(@(1,Amt_))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Amt": "totalAmount[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]